# Javascript equivalent of oracle forms

Tags: javascript, ajax, oracle, oracleforms

Oracle Forms has a lot of built-in events ( triggers ) e.g. WHEN-BUTTON-PRESSED, KEY-DOWN etc . Does anybody know of an HTML/Javascript/Ajax/Java framework/library equivalent for this ? I am trying to convert a Forms application into J2EE, and would greatly benefit from an existing library if it does really exist.

Thanks

Comment: No. I am looking at a open source, j2ee architecture to host this app.  Does OAF have anything out-of-the box ?

Answer (score 1):

> "What I am looking for, is actually, javascript implementation of
>   oracle forms standard built-ins. "

Most of the people moving away fromn Oracle Forms have gone either to ApEx or ADF.  Both are Oracle frameworks.

I think the set of people who both know Oracle Forms and want to develop a FOSS JavaScript framework replicating it is a Venn diagram with a very small intersection.  So, good luck with this.

---

Update for 2017: Oracle Forms is a tool for building user-focused data input-and-retrieval applications against an Oracle database. It is well designed for this task so it's instructive that Oracle didn't build a Forms-to-J2EE convertor. Oracle E-Business Suite is the largest Forms codebase yet Oracle chose to rebuild Apps from scratch, rather than convert them. This is because J2EE architecture is so different from Forms.

It's also instructive that Oracle spent over fifteen years trying to find a pure Java/JavaScript replacement for Forms. At the time of writing Oracle Forms is still going strong. Check out [the Forms 12c list of new features](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/forms/documentation/oracleforms-12210-newfeatures-2906037.pdf).

Answer (score 0):

Javascipt provides multiple events out of the box, a List of which by browser support is available here:
http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/events/index.html

Examples of listening for and responding to events:
http://www.w3schools.com/dhtml/dhtml_events.asp

Comment: Hi mwrf, thanks. What you've listed talks about standard brower/javascript compatibility. What I am looking for, is actually, javascript implementation of oracle forms standard built-ins. (http://download.oracle.com/otn_hosted_doc/forms/forms/A73152_01.pdf)

Comment: @user591831 why don't you use the tools build into the platform rather then emulating some abstraction layer on top of it? You  realise there are more tools in your toolbox then your hammer right? You realise not everything is a nail right? The road your walking down is the road of epic pain

Answer (score 0):

mwrf provides good info on javascript related events. JQuery and YUI are great Javascript libraries that enables you to develop listeners/events if you're looking for more advanced Javascript implementations - http://jquery.com/ and http://yuilibrary.com/.

If you're moving to J2EE have you considered Oracle Application Development Framework (ADF)? ADF is powerful framework built on J2EE standards. To do ADF development you use an IDE called JDeveloper (free), to develop applications in ADF. JDeveloper and ADF greatly simplifies and speeds up J2EE development. Just like Oracle Forms, JDeveloper uses a declarative and visual approach to development while retaining all the benefits of J2EE development. Thus in terms of a transition from Forms to J2EE development, ADF and JDeveloper are a much smoother transition.

Check it out: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/jdev/downloads/index.html

There are also tools that help you automate a migration specifically Forms to ADF - check out my link below :)

Thank you,

Gavin

http://www.pitss.com